# Tab and Backspace in the mode of insert spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode settings: "editor.insertSpaces" : true, "editor.tabSize": 3

If a current line is empty or contains spaces only, on pressing Tab key VSCode inserts a lot of spaces to reach a position of the first symbol of the first previous not empty string (instead of inserting simply 3 spaces). Is it possible that on pressing Tab key VSCode inserts 3 spaces independently of content of the current line?

If a symbol which is erased by pressing BS is the last in the line (i.e. after erasing the symbol the line will contain spaces only), VSCode erases not only the symbol but one or two previous spaces to set the cursor at the nearest 'Tab position'. Is it possible that on pressing Tab key VSCode erases 1 symbol always?